# Cannot access MySQL database on Google Cloud

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am new to **Google Cloud**. I have deploy lamp package in Google Cloud. I have a server address i.e: `150.200.100.10` and when in type  `150.200.100.10/phpmyadmin` I can login to my phpMyAdmin.

Of course if I type `150.200.100.10/index.htm`l I can see that `It Works` and if I type `150.200.100.10/index.php` I can see that php is runing in my server successfully as well. 
I am using the following `php` script that works in localhost for me:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','testpassword') or die($connect_error);
    mysql_select_db('mydatabase')or die($connect_error);

?>
```

I change it to following in order to upload it and work in Google Cloud:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect('150.200.100.10','root','testpassword') or die($connect_error);
    mysql_select_db('mydatabase')or die($connect_error);

?>
```

It gives the message that: `cannot connect`. What can be the problem here?

Do I have to go to Google Cloud, on Cloud SQL first and create an instance? Any other suggestions?

Comment: HAve you tried for server to use localhost?

Comment: I have test it in my localhost at my laptop and it works if you mean this

Comment: No, on google cloud code use localhost instead of his ip, from google cloud php you will be able to use the db =)

Comment: That's because to use IP in server the server need to allow that, there a lot of configurations, etc =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `IP` to `localhost`

```
<?php

  mysql_connect('localhost','root','testpassword') or die($connect_error);
               //^^^^^^^^^Change the 'IP' to 'localhost'
  mysql_select_db('mydatabase')or die($connect_error);

?>
```